# Viewing websites offline - how to get around unneeded ajax and jquery manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, offline-caching, offline-browsing

**I am trying to view a webpage offline.** The page is profoundly simple. It has a javascript video player that is interacting with an **HTML5 video** element. The video element specifies a url for a video. **So I am simply trying to get video playback in an offline saved version of the page.**

I downloaded the page using Firefox, and I see that **all assets are saved offline**. I also setup a local web server to view the page as **https://localhost/somepage.html**.

In the HTML, the video player starts out as

```
<div class="jp-jplayer" id="jp_jplayer_1" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;">
    <img id="jp_poster_1" src="http://localhost/files/vidtb.jpg" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; display: inline;">
    <video id="jp_video_1" preload="none" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
        <source src="http://localhost/files/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

**In Chrome Developer Tools Console I don't see any errors.**

After a number of jquery checks/manipulations, as well as some javascript from the application (all which is saved offline), the above HTML is changed to

```
<div class="jp-jplayer" id="jp_jplayer_0" style="width: 480px; height: 270px;">
    <img id="jp_poster_0" style="width: 480px; height: 270px; display: none;">
    <video id="jp_video_0" preload="none" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    </video>
</div>
```

Fun stuff.

So I have tried debugging, and it is very tough because in Chrome I can't even select the video source attribute to add a watch, because the minute I view in Inspector, the source element has been removed.

I set some breakpoints and found that in this function:

```
$(".player.video").each(function (t, e) {
        var n = $(e), i = parseInt(get_html_attribute(n, "width")) || 480, o = parseInt(get_html_attribute(n, "height")) || 270, a = get_html_attribute(n, "source"), r = get_html_attribute(n, "poster"), s = get_html_attribute(n, "caption"), l = n.parents("component").first().hasClass("float-center"), c = {
            play_top: (o - 60) / 2,
            height: o,
            width: i
        }, u = "true" === get_html_attribute(n, "fullscreen");
        l ? c.play_left = 27 : c.play_left = (i - 60) / 2, n.html(bm.render_template("media", "video", c));
        var d = {poster: r, m4v: a};
        s && (d.track = s), u && (d.allowFullScreen = !0), n.find(".jp-jplayer").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", d)
            },
            play: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers")
            },
            solution: "flash, html",
            supplied: "m4v",
            swfPath: "/lib",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#" + e.id,
            size: {width: i + "px", height: o + "px", cssClass: ""},
            nativeVideoControls: {
                msie: /msie [0-6]/,
                ipad: /ipad.*?os [0-4]/,
                iphone: /iphone/,
                ipod: /ipod/,
                android_pad: /android [0-3](?!.*?mobile)/,
                android_phone: /android.*?mobile/,
                blackberry: /blackberry/,
                windows_ce: /windows ce/,
                webos: /webos/
            }
        }).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers")
        })
    })
```

the video source ends up being removed, but it is not unclear where and why.

I think what is happening, is the application assumes there are some needed ajax calls, and that the video is being accessed via CORS credentials. Or maybe something to do with headers and the javascript looking for headers that it expects from on online browser, or looking for various server response headers. But since I have downloaded the video, I have no need for AJAX calls, credential checking, etc, etc. Basically, I need to remove whatever application/jquery functionality is causing this. If I remove scripts altogether that doesn't get me anywhere since the video playback is done so via the scripts.

So... what would you do? How would you go about tracking down the parts of the code that are causing this? Does this issue immediately lead you to think of some typical culprit that I could check?

Thanks, and sorry I can't be more precise about the problem. I am a guitarist who knows some coding, but trying to unravel this issue (among 1000's of lies of javascript) is beyond my coding experience. I can fix things once I know the issue, but it is the troubleshooting stage that is proving to be insane.

Regards

Comment: Save the actual DOM as it is at the time you save the page, rather than the page's original source? `document.querySelector("html").outerHTML` is super useful for this.

Comment: The paged is saved as in the original, but with assets pointing to local storage. Do you mean save the DOM as is before the changes happen then reload that saved version after the changes? I have a feeling if I do that the page will still keep changing because of all sorts of event listeners that are going on...

Comment: Let's back up a tiny bit: you say you want to play the video locally, so is this _really_ a question about saving a page, or is it a question about "I want to play this video offline"? Because for the latter, the solution is "save the video".

Comment: Hi, I just  realized that the HTML I was saving was not the HTML that is initially loaded. which is why various jQuery operations were not seeing what the app expected. So instead of using FireFox Save As I just copied the HTML as seen in View Source. Now it is working. I could just save the video, but the video is part of an overall page with other info so I was trying to keep everything together. Thanks, Brian

Comment: Remember to then either post an answer to your question or if you don't think future visitors will benefit from your solution, delete your question.

Comment: Still working out some details then I am going to answer the question. I think I have a way to download the page by logging in with curl, using wget with cookie, downloading page and resources, then possibly rewriting the saved html if it is not what the DOM originally is on page load, but that is what I am trying to work out now - how to make wget or curl get me the html as it is before all the jquery and ajax stuff happens...

Comment: that's literally the only thing they _can_ do, neither wget nor curl do any interpretation, they only get data from the server and then you have to do something with that if you actually want it to "run", so if you need a page "as it is after certain user actions" you want to use something that lets you script with a headless browser, like Selenium or Cypress or something.